# Examining an inequality involving exponential functions and hyperbolic cosine

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

Let $a,b$ be real numbers with $0 < a < b$.

> **Problem**: I would like to prove/disprove that $$ \frac{a \cdot 2^x+ b \cdot 2^{-x}}{a+b} \leq \cosh(x \log{2})
> $$ is true for all real $x \geq 0$.

**Approach**:

- I defined a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $$ f(x) = \cosh(x \log{2}) - \frac{a \cdot 2^x+ b \cdot 2^{-x}}{a+b}.
  $$ In order to show the inequality, it suffices to show $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.
- I tried to plot the function for some chosen parameters like $a=1$ and $b=2$. In all those cases the function was non-negative, so I suppose that this inequality is true.
- It is $f(0) = 1-1 = 0 \geq 0$.
- Now $f$ is differentiable, so I computed
  $$ f'(x) = \frac{\log{2}}{2(a+b)} \big(a (2^x - 2^{-x} - 2^{x+1}) + b(2^x-2^{-x}+2^{-x+1} ) \big). $$
- I would be done if I could show that $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$, so $f$ is monotonically increasing and we get our desired result. However, I can not see how this can be shown.

Could you please help me with this problem? That would be nice, thank you in advance!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the fact $$\cosh\left(x\ln 2\right)=\frac{e^{-x\ln 2}+e^{x\ln2}}{2}=\frac{2^{-x}+2^{x}}{2},$$ to make the problem simpler and not have to use derivatives.

Comment: This form definitely looks easier to handle. However, how can I use this fact to avoid derivatives? In particular, what kind of relation can I establish between the first term in my function (your fraction) and the second term in my function (the other fraction)?

Comment: Once you substitute that in for the right-hand side, you can manipulate the inequality to get
$$\frac{\left(4^{x}-1\right)\left(a-b\right)}{a+b}\le0\implies\left(4^{x}-1\right)\left(a-b\right)\le0\implies4^{x}-1\ge0\implies 4^{x}\ge1,$$
which is true for all $x\ge0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

$$2^{x}-2^{-x}-2^{x+1}=2^x-2^{-x}-2\cdot2^x= -2^x-2^{-x}=-2(2^{x-1}+2^{-x-1}) = - 2 \left(\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}\right)  $$

Hence
$$2^{x}-2^{-x}-2^{x+1} = - 2 \left(\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}\right) = -2 \cosh(x \log 2)$$

Similarly
$$2^{x}-2^{-x}+2^{1-x}=2^x-2^{-x}+2\cdot2^{-x}= 2^x+2^{-x}=2(2^{x-1}+2^{-x-1}) =  2 \left(\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}\right)  $$

Hence

$$2^{x}-2^{-x}+2^{1-x}=  2 \left(\frac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}\right)  = 2 \cosh(x\log 2)$$

So with this the derivative is:
\begin{align}
f'(x)&= \frac{\log 2}{2 (a+b)} \left[-2a \cosh(x \log 2) + 2b \cosh(x \log 2)\right] \\
&= \frac{\log 2}{ a+b} \left[-a \cosh(x \log 2) + b \cosh(x \log 2)\right]\\
&=\log 2\frac{b-a}{a+b} \cosh(x\log2)
\end{align}

with $\log 2 >0$, $\frac{b-a}{a+b}>0$ since $a<b$, and $\cosh(x \log 2)>0$ since $\cosh$ is non-negative.

Therefore

$$f'(x)>0$$

as you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Big wall of algebra incoming:

\begin{align*}
\frac{a\cdot2^{x}+b\cdot2^{-x}}{a+b}\le\cosh\left(x\ln2\right)&\implies\frac{a\cdot2^{x}+\frac{b}{2^{x}}}{a+b}\le\frac{2^{x}+2^{-x}}{2}\\
&\implies\frac{a\cdot2^{x}+\frac{b}{2^{x}}}{a+b}\le\frac{2^{x}+\frac{1}{2^{x}}}{2}\\
&\implies\frac{a\cdot2^{2x}+b}{2^{x}\left(a+b\right)}\le\frac{2^{2x}+1}{2\cdot 2^{x}}\\
&\implies\frac{2^{2x}+b}{a+b}\le\frac{2^{2x}+1}{2}\\
&\implies\frac{a\cdot4^{x}+b}{a+b}\le\frac{4^{x}+1}{2}\\
&\implies\frac{a\cdot4^{x}+b}{a+b}-\frac{4^{x}+1}{2}\le0\\
&\implies\frac{2\left(a\cdot4^{x}+b\right)-\left(a+b\right)\left(4^{x}+1\right)}{2\left(a+b\right)}\le0\\
&\implies\frac{2a\cdot4^{x}+2b-a\cdot4^{x}-b\cdot4^{x}-a-b}{2\left(a+b\right)}\le0\\
&\implies\frac{4^{x}\left(2a-a-b\right)+b-a}{2\left(a+b\right)}\le0\\
&\implies\frac{4^{x}\left(a-b\right)+b-a}{2\left(a+b\right)}\le0\\
&\implies\frac{4^{x}\left(a-b\right)-\left(a-b\right)}{2\left(a+b\right)}\le0\\
&\implies\frac{\left(a-b\right)\left(4^{x}-1\right)}{2\left(a+b\right)}\le0\\
&\implies\left(a-b\right)\left(4^{x}-1\right)\le0\\
&\implies4^{x}-1\ge0\text{ since }a-b<0\\
&\implies4^{x}\ge1,
\end{align*}

which is true for all $x\ge0$.

If someone can find a pretty way to format this, then feel free to edit it.

Comment: Note that your conclusion is in the wrong direction. You might want to reverse the order of the statements or replace $\implies$ by $\impliedby$

Comment: Good point. I got carried away in the algebraic manipulation that I forgot what we were trying to show. For any readers, start with $x\ge0$ at the bottom and then work your way to the top, replacing $\implies$ with $\impliedby$ as Martin mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$
 \frac{a}{a+b} = \frac 12 \left( 1 - \frac{b-a}{a+b}\right) \, , \quad
\frac{b}{a+b} = \frac 12 \left( 1 + \frac{b-a}{a+b}\right)
$$
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{a \cdot 2^x + b \cdot 2^{-x}}{a+b} &= \left(\frac{2^x + 2^{-x}}{2}\right) - \frac{b-a}{a+b} \left(\frac{2^x - 2^{-x}}{2}\right) \\
 &= \cosh(x \log 2) - \frac{b-a}{a+b} \sinh(x \log 2) \\
 &\le \cosh(x \log 2) \, .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

*An alternative argument:* Fix $x \ge 0$. For $0 \le t \le \frac 12$ we have
$$
 t \cdot e^x + (1-t) \cdot e^{-x} \le \max(e^{-x}, \frac{2^x + 2^{-x}}{2}) = \frac{2^x + 2^{-x}}{2}
$$
because the left-hand side is a *linear* function of $t$ which attains its maximum at a boundary point of the interval $[0, \frac 12]$. Setting $t = \frac{a}{a+b}$ gives the desired conclusion.